# How to create specialization for a single method in a templated class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Many questions have been asked and they are similar to the one I am going to ask here, but they are not the same I think.

I have a templated class:

```
namespace app {
template <typename T>
class MyCLass {
public:
  void dosome();
  void doother();
}
} /*ns*/
```

And implementations:

```
template <typename T>
app::MyClass<T>::dosome() {}
template <typename T>
app::MyClass<T>::doother() {}
```

When I have an instance of that class to which a `char` is provided as template parameter, I want function `dosome()` to behave in a totally different way. 
But I just want that function to behave differently, everything else must still act the same.

I tried typing:

```
template<>
app::MyCLass<char>::dosome() {
}
```

But the compiler tells me that I am trying to create a specialization in a different namespace.

So when I have a code like this:

```
app::MyCLass<int> a;
app::MyCLass<char> b;
a.dosome(); // This must call the generic template definition
b.dosome(); // This must call the specialization
a.doother(); // This must call the generic template definition
b.doother(); // This must call the generic template definition
```

In other questions I saw people creating totally different specialization of the entire class. But I only want a specialization of a single method.

Comment: You have to specialize the entire class, not just a single method

Comment: You have to specialize the entire class first.

Comment: But in that way I must define again all method implementations...

Comment: Do I really have to write the code for `doother`??? It seems so strange to me...

Comment: yes, that is how template specialization works for classes

Comment: You forget to add the namespace in your sample (that the error refers to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want: http://ideone.com/oKTFPC

// Header

```
namespace My
{

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    void dosome();
    void doother();
};

template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::dosome() {}
template <typename T> void MyClass<T>::doother() {}

template<> void MyClass<char>::dosome();

}
```

// cpp or in header

```
template<>
void My::MyClass<char>::dosome() {
    std::cout << "specialization" << std::endl;
}
```

or using alternate notation

```
namespace My {
template<>
void MyClass<char>::dosome() {
    std::cout << "specialization" << std::endl;
}
}
```

Comment: I keep forgetting that this is allowed. +1

Comment: So it is actually what I was trying to do but you use the specialization syntax both in the header and in the implementation????

Comment: You may implement all stuff in the header if you want, but to use the syntax `My::Myclass<char>`, you have to declare it (the specialization) in the namespace before.

Comment: So basically you are declaring the partial specialization and then implementing it...

Answer (score 2):

One option would be tag dispatching:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  void dosome() { dosome_impl( T() ); }

private:

  void dosome_impl(char) { /* char stuff */ }  
  template<typename U>
  void dosome_impl(U) { /* usual stuff */ }
};
```

Another one is `enable_if` idiom:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
  template<typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,char>::value>::type
  dosome() { /* char stuff */ }

  template<typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U,char>::value>::type
  dosome() { /* normal stuff */ }
};
```

And yet another one is to move that single function to a base class that you can specialize:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass_base {
    dosome() { /* usual stuff */ }
};

template<>
struct MyClass_base<char> {
    dosome() { /* char stuff */ } 
};

template <typename T>
class MyClass : private MyClass_Base<T> {
public:
    // nothing special here
};
```

Comment: @Andry Many people believe it, but Dawkins says there's no god. I'll stay out of that debate :)