# How to specialize a templated member-function into a templated class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, template-specialization

With regards to this question: [How to create specialization for a single method in a templated class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701788/how-to-create-specialization-for-a-single-method-in-a-templated-class-in-c) ...

I have this class:

```
template <typename T>
class MyCLass {
public:
  template <typename U>
  U myfunct(const U& x);
};
// Generic implementation
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
U MyCLass<T>::myfunct(const U& x) {...}
```

And I want to specialize `myfunct` for `double`s.

This is what I do:

```
// Declaring specialization
template <>
template <typename T>
double MyCLass<T>::myfunct(const double& x);

// Doing it
template <>
template <typename T>
double MyCLass<T>::myfunct(const double& x) {...}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Oh yeah... sorry fixing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible in C++. You can only specialise a member function template if you also specialise all enclosing class templates.

But anyway, it's generally better to *overload* function templates instead of specialising them (for details see this [article by Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)). So simply do this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyCLass {
public:
  template <typename U>
  U myfunct(const U& x);

  double myfunct(double x);
};
```